# Getting wrong result when adding random values in string format

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm trying to make a script that receives a number of desired random numbers as input, and then generates and prints them.

However, my script adds the numbers instead of joining the strings. I would like for the strings to join so it would generate the pins like:

Enter the amount of lunch pins to generate:
10

```
26141
128111
937502
2436
56516
83623
246317
```

My code:

```
import random

PTG = int(input("Enter the amount of pins to generate: \n"))
PG = 0
PS = ""

while PTG > PG:
 RN1 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN2 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN3 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN4 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN5 = random.randint(0, 10)
 RN6 = random.randint(0, 10)
 if RN1 == 0:
   PS += "0"
 elif RN1 == 1:
   PS += "1"
 elif RN1 == 2:
   PS += "2"
 elif RN1 == 3:
   PS += "3"
 elif RN1 == 4:
   PS += "4"
 elif RN1 == 5:
   PS += "5"
 elif RN1 == 6:
   PS += "6"
 elif RN1 == 7:
   PS += "7"
 elif RN1 == 8:
   PS += "8"
 elif RN1 == 9:
   PS += "9"
 elif RN2 == 0:
   PS += "0"
 elif RN2 == 1:
   PS += "1"
 elif RN2 == 2:
   PS += "2"
 elif RN2 == 3:
   PS += "3"
 elif RN2 == 4:
   PS += "4"
 elif RN2 == 5:
   PS += "5"
 elif RN2 == 6:
   PS += "6"
 elif RN2 == 7:
   PS += "7"
 elif RN2 == 8:
   PS += "8"
 elif RN2 == 9:
   PS += "9"
 if RN3 == 0:
   PS += "0"
 elif RN3 == 1:
   PS += "1"
 elif RN3 == 2:
   PS += "2"
 elif RN3 == 3:
   PS += "3"
 elif RN3 == 4:
   PS += "4"
 elif RN3 == 5:
   PS += "5"
 elif RN3 == 6:
   PS += "6"
 elif RN3 == 7:
   PS += "7"
 elif RN3 == 8:
   PS += "8"
 elif RN3 == 9:
   PS += "9"
 elif RN4 == 0:
   PS += "0"
 elif RN4 == 1:
   PS += "1"
 elif RN4 == 2:
   PS += "2"
 elif RN4 == 3:
   PS += "3"
 elif RN4 == 4:
   PS += "4"
 elif RN4 == 5:
   PS += "5"
 elif RN4 == 6:
   PS += "6"
 elif RN4 == 7:
   PS += "7"
 elif RN4 == 8:
   PS += "8"
 elif RN4 == 9:
   PS += "9"
 elif RN5 == 0:
   PS += "0"
 elif RN5 == 1:
   PS += "1"
 elif RN5 == 2:
   PS += "2"
 elif RN5 == 3:
   PS += "3"
 elif RN5 == 4:
   PS += "4"
 elif RN5 == 5:
   PS += "5"
 elif RN5 == 6:
   PS += "6"
 elif RN5 == 7:
   PS += "7"
 elif RN5 == 8:
   PS += "8"
 elif RN5 == 9:
   PS += "9"
 elif RN5 == 10:
   PS += ""
 elif RN6 == 0:
   PS += "0"
 elif RN6 == 1:
   PS += "1"
 elif RN6 == 2:
   PS += "2"
 elif RN6 == 3:
   PS += "3"
 elif RN6 == 4:
   PS += "4"
 elif RN6 == 5:
   PS += "5"
 elif RN6 == 6:
   PS += "6"
 elif RN6 == 7:
   PS += "7"
 elif RN6 == 8:
   PS += "8"
 elif RN6 == 9:
   PS += "9"
 print(PS)
 PG += 1
 PS = ""
```

Python version: 3.7.4

Comment: "my script adds the numbers instead of joining the strings" actually your problem looks much more likely that you just have `elif` at the first check for a few of your variables so they just never end up getting checked. if you make sure the first check for all variables is an `if` that might be the whole solution. (other than improvements to the way you are converting from integer to string of course.)

Comment: Right now only `RN1` and `RN3` start with their own `if`, all the others are only going to be added if the previous variables none of the conditions come true because they only have `elif` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code step by step:

First, notice that `random.randint` returns an int. Therefore you need to convert it to a String.
 You can use the [str()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) function in order to convert it to a string, for example:

```
str(random.randint(0, 9))+"9"
```

will return a string like `59` (for example).

Therefore, when initializing each random number, you need to do it the following way, for example:

```
RN1 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
```

Then, instead of checking the value of each random variable, you can just add them up:

```
PS = RN1 + RN2 + RN3 + RN4 + RN5 + RN6
```

Furthermore, instead of using six different variables to handle the random values, you can use a `for` loop for the first four which are from 0 to 9:

```
for x in range(4):
    RN = str(random.randint(0, 9))
    PS += RN
```

And then add the remaining two that are between 0 and 10:

```
PS += str(random.randint(0, 10))
PS += str(random.randint(0, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

# PTG = int(input("Enter the amount of pins to generate: \n"))
PTG = 10
PG = 0
PS = ""

while PTG > PG:
 RN1 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN2 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN3 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN4 = random.randint(0, 9)
 RN5 = random.randint(0, 10)
 RN6 = random.randint(0, 10)

 PS = str(RN1) + str(RN2) + str(RN3) + str(RN4) + str(RN5) + str(RN6)
 print(int(PS))

 PG += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When I understand your code right, you want to generate n pins with 6 digits. You can do that a lot easier than you want to:

```
number_of_pins = int(input("Enter the amount of pins to generate: \n"))
pins = []
for i in range(number_of_pins):
    pins.append(str(random.randint(100_000, 999_999)))
print(" ".join(pins))
```

Explaination:

`pins = []` makes a new empty list to store the pins

`for i in range(n):` executes the following indented block n times.

`pins.append(random.randint(100_000, 999_999))` generates a random number and adds it to the list. 100000 is the first number with 6 digits and 999999 is the last. (The _ is just for readability). str() converts it to a string.

print(" ".join(pins)) joins all the pins and puts a space between.